# Jest TypeError: Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined

Tags: typescript, jestjs

I'm trying to execute the following code in a test:

```js
import Airtable from "airtable";

const base: string = 'xxx'
const getClient = () => new Airtable({apiKey: 'xxx'});

export async function getAirtableData(): Promise<string[]> {
    return []
}
```

My test:

```js
test('Airtable to ElasticSearch', async () => {
  expect(await getAirtableData()).toBe([])
});
```

But when I run the test (using Jest), I get the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined
```

EDIT: Running the code manually using `ts-node` without using Jest works just fine.

Google only returns issues related to React, which I'm not using. What might be the issue?

Comment: Is the original code exactly like this, does the original code involve a "this"?

Comment: This is the original code, yes. The error is reported on the line with `import Airtable from "airtable";` I'm using `airtable` version `^0.10.1`

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you have a look at your typescript configuration,

the following worked for me:

`tsconfig.json`:

```
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": ["ES2019"],
    "target": "ES2019",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true
  }
}
```

`package.json`:

```json
{
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/jest": "27.0.1",
    "airtable": "^0.10.1",
    "jest": "27.1.1",
    "ts-node": "10.2.1",
    "typescript": "4.4.3",
    "ts-jest": "27.0.5"
  }
}
```

`jest.config.js`:

```js
module.exports = {
  preset: 'ts-jest',
  testEnvironment: 'node',
};
```

now using your code example, my `main.ts`:

```
import Airtable from "airtable";

const base: string = 'xxx'
const getClient = () => new Airtable({apiKey: 'xxx'});

export async function getAirtableData(): Promise<string[]> {
    return []
}
```

and `main.test.ts`:

```
import {getAirtableData} from './main'

test('Airtable to ElasticSearch', async () => {
  expect(await getAirtableData()).toEqual([])
});
```

it works as expected:

[image]